# Have a .bat autorun when a .exe is called

Tags: batch-file, autorun

Is it possible to have a .bat file be automatically execute when a specific .exe file is called? I believe you could do it with a loop in the .bat file checking if the .exe is in the task manager if I did do it this way how many resources would it be using?? Using Windows 7. Thank you for any help

Comment: You'll want a process that listens for WMI events related to process creation.

Comment: Or rename yourexe.exe to yourexemain.exe, and create a dummy replacement yourexe.exe which calls the main one, and also launches a batch file :)

Answer (score 2):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:loop
tasklist|FIND /i "yourexe.exe" >NUL
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO your exe is running&GOTO :EOF 
choice /t 1 /d y /n >NUL 
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO :EOF 
GOTO loop
```

... looks to see whether yourexe.exe is running every 1 sec; terminate on ^C or N

Uses insignificant resources.